# AddClipboardFormatListener was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm creating a program to monitor the clipboard changing in Windows, in C++.

I would use the function `AddClipboardFormatListener`, but the compiler gives me this error:

> `AddClipboardFormatListener` was not declared in this scope

even when I add the `windows.h` library.

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: I hope we can if you can post essential part of your code

Comment: You probably haven't defined NTDDI_VERSION etc appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddClipboardFormatListener()`, `RemoveClipboardFormatListener()`, and `GetUpdatedClipboardFormats()` are only available on Vista and later.  On XP and earlier, you need to use `SetClipboardViewer()` and `ChangeClipboardChain()` instead.

In the Win32 SDK, the listener functions are declared only if `WINVER` is at least `0x0600` (aka `_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA`), meaning your project is configured to compile an executable specifically for Vista+ only.

See [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx) for more details.

If you are compiling your project with a lesser `WINVER` value for compatibility with XP or earlier, you cannot statically link to the listener functions at compile-time, otherwise your executable will fail to load when run on XP and earlier.  If you want to use the listener functions on Vista+ in such an executable, you will have to load the functions dynamically at runtime using `GetProcAddress()`.

Comment: Another option to make run-time dynamic linking easier to use is delay-loading of DLLs (see [Linker Support for Delay-Loaded DLLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx)). To deal with imports not available for a particular system you can implement custom fallback handling. The is explained under [Understanding the Helper Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09t6x5ds.aspx).